# Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() while using reactive output in reactiveValues function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to get a reactiveValue that is depending on a reactive. In the real code (this is a very simplified version), I load a dataset interactively. It changes when pushing the buttons (prevBtn/nextBtn). I need to know the number of rows in the dataset, using this to plot the datapoints with different colors.

The question: Why can't I use the reactive ro() in the reactiveValues function?

For understanding: Why is the error saying "`You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.`", although ro() is used inside a reactive context.

The error is definitely due to vals(), I already checked the rest.

The code :

```
library(shiny)
datasets <- list(mtcars, iris, PlantGrowth)
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        titlePanel("Simplified example"),
        tableOutput("cars"),
        actionButton("prevBtn", icon = icon("arrow-left"), ""),
        actionButton("nextBtn", icon = icon("arrow-right"), ""),
        verbatimTextOutput("rows")
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$cars <- renderTable({
        head(dat())
    })
    dat <- reactive({
        if (is.null(rv$nr)) {
            d <- mtcars
        }
        else{
            d <- datasets[[rv$nr]]
        }
    })
    rv <- reactiveValues(nr = 1)
    set_nr <- function(direction) {
        rv$nr <- rv$nr + direction
    }
    observeEvent(input$nextBtn, {
        set_nr(1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$prevBtn, {
        set_nr(-1)
    })
    ro <- reactive({
        nrow(dat())
    })
    output$rows <- renderPrint({
        print(paste(as.character(ro()), "rows"))
    })
    vals <- reactiveValues(needThisForLater = 30 * ro())
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error in `.getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext()` :

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
vals <- reactiveValues(needThisForLater = reactive(30 * ro()))
```

Not everything in a `reactiveValues` list is assumed to be reactive. It's also a good place to store constant values. So since it's trying to evaluate the parameter you are passing at run time and you are not calling that line in a reactive environment, you get that error. So by just wrapping it in a call to `reactive()`, you provide a reactive environment for `ro()` to be called in.